# Understanding Netflix Eureka Leases - Service Keeps Unregistering

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I keep having this intermittent issue with one of my Spring Cloud Eureka clients, but none of the others.  When I start my "NCLSEARCHSERVICE" it registers itself with Eureka, shows "UP" in Eureka for about 30 seconds to a minute, then unregisters itself.  Here are the logs from the Eureka server that show it registering all of my other services, but then failing to register my search service because "Lease is not registered".  Sorry for the poor formatting of the log file copy/paste.

> ```
> 2015-10-01 09:48:55.144  WARN 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-4] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : DS: Registry: lease doesn't
> ```
>
> exist, registering resource: CONFIGSERVICE - 172.18.100.120 2015-10-01
>   09:48:55.145  WARN 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-4]
>   c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found (Renew):
>   CONFIGSERVICE - 172.18.100.120 2015-10-01 09:48:55.147  WARN 6470 ---
>   [nio-8761-exec-2] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : DS:
>   Registry: lease doesn't exist, registering resource: ZUULSERVER -
>   eXploit-Zuul 2015-10-01 09:48:55.147  WARN 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-2]
>   c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found (Renew):
>   ZUULSERVER - eXploit-Zuul 2015-10-01 09:48:55.419  INFO 6470 ---
>   [nio-8761-exec-7] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      :
>   Registered instance id 172.18.100.120 with status UP 2015-10-01
>   09:48:55.423  INFO 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-8]
>   com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id
>   eXploit-Zuul with status UP 2015-10-01 09:48:55.778  INFO 6470 ---
>   [nio-8761-exec-9] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      :
>   Registered instance id 172.18.100.120 with status UP 2015-10-01
>   09:48:55.809  INFO 6470 --- [io-8761-exec-10]
>   com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id
>   eXploit-Zuul with status UP 2015-10-01 09:49:05.416  WARN 6470 ---
>   [nio-8761-exec-3] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : DS:
>   Registry: lease doesn't exist, registering resource: GEOSERVER -
>   172.18.100.155 2015-10-01 09:49:05.418  WARN 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found
>   (Renew): GEOSERVER - 172.18.100.155 2015-10-01 09:49:05.441  INFO 6470
>   --- [nio-8761-exec-5] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id 172.18.100.155 with status STARTING 2015-10-01
>   09:49:05.607  INFO 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-4]
>   com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id
>   172.18.100.155 with status STARTING 2015-10-01 09:49:05.948  INFO 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-8] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id 172.18.100.197 with status UP 2015-10-01
>   09:49:06.107  INFO 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-9]
>   com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id
>   172.18.100.197 with status UP 2015-10-01 09:49:11.175  WARN 6470 --- [io-8761-exec-10] c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Time to
>   sync, since the last dirty timestamp differs - ReplicationInstance id
>   : 172.18.100.155,Registry : 1443651207024 Incoming: 1443651408538
>   Replication: false 2015-10-01 09:49:11.197  INFO 6470 ---
>   [nio-8761-exec-3] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      :
>   Registered instance id 172.18.100.155 with status UP 2015-10-01
>   09:49:11.562  WARN 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-5]
>   c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Time to sync, since the
>   last dirty timestamp differs - ReplicationInstance id :
>   172.18.100.155,Registry : 1443651408538 Incoming: 1443651207024 Replication: true 2015-10-01 09:49:11.607  INFO 6470 ---
>   [nio-8761-exec-4] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      :
>   Registered instance id 172.18.100.155 with status UP 2015-10-01
>   09:50:03.859  INFO 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-6]
>   c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Found (Cancel):
>   NCLSEARCHSERVICE - 172.18.100.197 2015-10-01 09:50:03.870  INFO 6470
>   --- [io-8761-exec-10] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id 172.18.100.197 with status UP 2015-10-01
>   09:50:04.120  INFO 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-2]
>   com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry      : Registered instance id
>   172.18.100.197 with status UP 2015-10-01 09:50:04.130  INFO 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-5] c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Found
>   (Cancel): NCLSEARCHSERVICE - 172.18.100.197 2015-10-01 09:50:04.745 
>   WARN 6470 --- [nio-8761-exec-3] com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry
>   : DS: Registry: cancel failed because Lease is not registered for:
>   NCLSEARCHSERVICE:172.18.100.197

The logs for my search service don't seem to show anything interesting, only that it saw in Eureka that it was previously down and now it's changing the status to up:

> 2015-09-30 17:59:14.164  INFO 9056 --- [           main]
>   c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Unregistering application
>   nclSearchService with eureka with status DOWN 2015-09-30 17:59:14.164 
>   INFO 9056 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient 
>   : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [current=DOWN,
>   previous=UP] 2015-09-30 17:59:14.208  INFO 9056 --- [nfoReplicator-0]
>   com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_NCLSEARCHSERVICE/172.18.100.197: registering
>   service... 2015-09-30 17:59:14.217  INFO 9056 --- [nfoReplicator-0]
>   com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_NCLSEARCHSERVICE/172.18.100.197 - registration status:
>   204 2015-09-30 17:59:14.218  INFO 9056 --- [           main]
>   com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
>   DiscoveryClient_NCLSEARCHSERVICE/172.18.100.197 - deregister  status:
>   200 2015-09-30 17:59:14.218  INFO 9056 --- [           main]
>   c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Registering application
>   nclSearchService with eureka with status UP

My config is a mess right now, because I keep experimenting with different values and configurations, but here is the basic values I'm working with:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
#      uri: http://${CONFIG_SERVER_URL:172.18.100.120:8888}
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: CONFIGSERVICE
  application:
    name: nclSearchService


eureka:
  client:
    enable-self-preservation: false
#    registerWithEureka: true
#    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://172.18.100.120:8761/eureka/
#    healthcheck:
#      enabled: true
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 30

# items below are listed in the config server
service:
    name: nclSearchService

security:
  sessions: NEVER

#instance:
#  preferIpAddress: true
#server:
#  port: 8080
#  contextPath: /
```

You can see that I'm also loading config dynamically from a config service, but that just loads application specific variables.

In the past, if I keep randomly messing with the config on my search service, I can get it to stabilize on Eureka.  But then the problem re-appears and I can never pin point what is actually causing it.  It seems to be an issue with Eureka and it's instance registry, but I can't quite figure out what to do to fix it.

UPDATE 1:
The NCLSEARCHSERVICE is using spring-boot-dependencies 1.2.5.RELEASE and spring-cloud-netflix 1.1.0.M1.  My Eureka server is using the same version of the spring boot dependencies, but spring-cloud-netflix 1.0.3.RELEASE.  I tried updating the search service to see if that had any effect on my issue.  If it is recommended that all services use the same version, I can move either up/down a version.

Only once in my troubleshooting did I attempt to call /refresh on my search service.  If I remember correctly, it went through the same process of showing up temporarily and then being removed from the registry again.

UPDATE 2:
I may have narrowed down the issue... I had a config server running on port 8888 on the same VM as the Eureka server running on port 8761.  I disabled the dynamic configuration in my search service and moved the contents of the nclSearchService.yml from the config server to application.yml on my search service.  The search service has registered with Eureka and has been stable for about 10 minutes.

This is odd because even though my search service is no longer configured to use the config service, the config service is still deployed and running.  Also, even when the search service was deregistering, you could see in the logs that it was successfully pulling the nclSearchService.yml file from the config service, and it would boot all the way up and be usable with the properties that were pulled from the config service.

Not sure what any of that means :)

Comment: What version are you using? Are you calling `/refresh`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Mr. Gibb.  Please see update 1 in the original post.

Comment: I would recommend using the same versions of spring-cloud-netflix and se if that helps.

Comment: I moved my search service and Eureka service to 1.1.0.M1.  My Zuul server and config server are still on 1.0.3.RELEASE.  The same issue still occurs.  The other services are fine, but just my search service fails.  One thing that keeps sticking out is that the services that work fine all show up in the Eurkea logs as "Not Found (Renew): CONFIGSERVICE - 172.18.100.120", but the search service always shows up as " Found (Cancel): NCLSEARCHSERVICE - 172.18.100.197".  The only other thing that differentiates this service is that it's the only one using my spring cloud config service.

Comment: See update 2 -- the issue seems to center around using my spring cloud config service.

Comment: do you have a project that you could share? I'm afraid without seeing it we could talk till we're blue in the face.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the projects.  I just tried to move the config service to it's own VM, then re-enabled the dynamic configuration on my search service.  Ended with the same results of the search service de-registering itself.  This is bizarre...

Comment: I don't think it's where the config service is, but what it is sending to the clients.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91176/discussion-between-bal-and-spencergibb).

Comment: If you want to chat, we use gitter https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the docker memory from 2GB to 4GB fixed this for me. Maybe increasing the VM memory will fix this for you as well.